# How to enable any 5 checkboxes out of 15 checkboxes?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am new in android development.

I am making a mobile application in which I have taken a horizontalscrollview in which I have taken 15 checkboxes out of which I have to select only 5 checkboxes at a time and make others disable.

It means as soon as I select 5 checkboxes out of 15 checkboxes, it makes other checkboxes disable.

Please assist me guys for the above question.

Answer (score 1):

Add an action listener to the checkboxes that increments/decrements a counter each time one is selected/deselected and when the counter hits 5 loop through the checkboxes and disable the unselected ones and reenable them when the counter is less than 5.